# Is it possible to override a Spring Namespace handler?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

SpringMVC comes with a 'mvc' namespace handled by (unsurprisingly) 'MvcNamespaceHandler', defined like this :

```
public class MvcNamespaceHandler extends NamespaceHandlerSupport {

public void init() {
    registerBeanDefinitionParser("annotation-driven", new AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser());
    registerBeanDefinitionParser("default-servlet-handler", new DefaultServletHandlerBeanDefinitionParser());
    registerBeanDefinitionParser("interceptors", new InterceptorsBeanDefinitionParser());       
    registerBeanDefinitionParser("resources", new ResourcesBeanDefinitionParser());
    registerBeanDefinitionParser("view-controller", new ViewControllerBeanDefinitionParser());
}
```

}

I would like to modify the behavior of the namespace so that mvc:resources element are handled by a custom ResourcesBeanDefinitionParser (in my case, to replace a ResourcesHttpRequestHandler, create by the bean definition parser, with a custom implementation).

I would like to know if it is possible to do that whithout going through the hassle of creating a brand new namespace (as described here http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/extensible-xml.html).

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom namespace to register a different ResourceHttpRequestHandler, but like you have said, it is definitely a good amount of work.

A better approach may be to simply define the bean explicitly in configuration this way, the ResourcesBeanDefinition essentially does this:

```
<bean name="resourceHandler" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/resources/</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="urlMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="/resources/**" value-ref="resourceHandler"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You can simply replace the resourceHandler with your implementation here.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this very same issue today (but for the context namespaceHandler). I've done it on a hacky way.

create a file named `spring.handlers` in your `META-INF` folder and put a declaration overriding the default schema. In your case, something like this:

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc=org.springframework.web.servlet.config.MvcNamespaceHandler
```

for

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc=YOURBEANPATH.
```

Perhaps you will need to declare the `spring.handlers` file inside a jar with a name that starts with a letter greater than 's' (in my case it was 't'), as spring will merge the `spring.handlers` definitions by the order they are found.

For debugging information, take a look at `DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver#getHandlerMappings`.

Comment: JARs are not necessarily loaded in alphabetical order of name. This may work for you on this occasion, but it could all go horribly wrong if you add another library, move the JARs to a new filesystem, ...